# SharePoint List - calculate value based on Date and Department Columns

Tags: sharepoint

New to using sharepoint and what to know if it is possible in a sharepoint list to calculate multiple items based on Date and location?
I have the following columns

1. Date
2. Location
3. Activity
4. Number of hours to complete task
5. Hours for the day

The person entering the data will use one entry per activity so may have 3 activities equaling 10.5 hours for the day.
Can I add the "Number of hours to complete task" together for the day based on the "date" and "location" and save that into the "Hours for the day" column?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint caculated column can only get the data in current item, it cannot get other items' data.

For you requirement, you may need to use some custom js code to achieve this.